# Using sed to find and replace within matched substrings

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to use `sed` to process a property file such as:

```
java.home=/usr/bin/java
groovy-home=/usr/lib/groovy
workspace.home=/build/me/my-workspace
```

I'd like to replace the `.`'s and `-`'s with `_`'s but only up to the `=`'s token. The output would be

```
java_home=/usr/bin/java
groovy_home=/usr/lib/groovy
workspace_home=/build/me/my-workspace
```

I've tried various approaches including using addresses but I keep failing. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I would assume that you can't do this with sed. Can't you use awk or a generic scripting language?

Answer (score 1):

**awk** makes life easier in this case:

```
awk -F= -vOFS="=" '{gsub(/[.-]/,"_",$1)}1' file
```

here you go:

```
kent$  echo "java.home=/usr/bin/java
groovy-home=/usr/lib/groovy
workspace.home=/build/me/my-workspace"|awk -F= -vOFS="=" '{gsub(/[.-]/,"_",$1)}1'
java_home=/usr/bin/java
groovy_home=/usr/lib/groovy
workspace_home=/build/me/my-workspace
```

if you really want to do with sed (**gnu sed**)

```
sed -r 's/([^=]*)(.*)/echo -n \1 \|sed -r "s:[-.]:_:g"; echo -n \2/ge' file
```

same example:

```
kent$  echo "java.home=/usr/bin/java
groovy-home=/usr/lib/groovy
workspace.home=/build/me/my-workspace"|sed -r 's/([^=]*)(.*)/echo -n \1 \|sed -r "s:[-.]:_:g"; echo -n \2/ge'
java_home=/usr/bin/java
groovy_home=/usr/lib/groovy
workspace_home=/build/me/my-workspace
```

Answer (score 1):

What about...

```
$ echo foo.bar=/bla/bla-bla | sed -e 's/\([^-.]*\)[-.]\([^-.]*=.*\)/\1_\2/'
foo_bar=/bla/bla-bla
```

This won't work for the case where you have more than 1 dot or dash one the left, though. I'll have to think about it further.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use `AWK` instead of `sed`:

```
awk -F"=" '{gsub("\\.|-","_",$1); print $1"="$2;}' <file.properties>
```

Output:

```
java_home/usr/bin/java
groovy_home/usr/lib/groovy
workspace_home/build/me/my-workspace
```

Comment: i think u missed to added the OFS here

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/=/\n&/;h;y/-./__/;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

["You wait ages for a bus..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696606/substitute-characters-between-specific-strings)

Answer (score 0):

This works with any number of dots and hyphens in the line and does **not** require GNU sed:

```
sed 'h; s/.*=//; x; s/=.*//; s/[.-]/_/g; G; s/\n/=/'  < data
```

Here's how:

- h: save a copy of the line in the hold space
- s: throw away everything before the equal sign in the pattern space
- x: swap the pattern and hold
- s: blow away everything after the `=` in the pattern
- s: replaces dots and hyphens with underscores
- G: join the pattern and hold with a newline
- s: replace that newline with an equal to glue it all back together

Answer (score 0):

Other way using sed

```
sed -re 's/(.*)([.-])(.*)=(.*)/\1_\3=\4/g' temp.txt
```

Output

```
java_home=/usr/bin/java
groovy_home=/usr/lib/groovy
workspace_home=/build/me/my-workspace
```

In case there are more than `.-` on left hand side then this

```
sed -re ':a; s/^([^.-]+)([\.-])(.*)=/\1_\3=/1;t a' temp.txt
```